# What measures to take if the tablet swallowed is still stuck in the throat even after drinking loads of water?

Tags: health, medicine

Sometimes when we take tablets, no matter how big or small the tablet is, it feels like it sticks in the throat no matter how much water we drink. Is there a quick remedy to this?

Comment: Did you try eating a piece of dry bread?

Comment: Hi P H, Welcome to Lifehacks. The proper way to "thank" someone for their contribution is to "vote" the answer up as mentioned in the [Tour]. This is the way you earn reputation points. You're welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/22791/how-can-i-swallow-pills-more-easily

Comment: Have you tried drinking water before, during and after the tablet?  Lubricating your throat before swallowing the tablet may help.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it feels as if the tablet is "stuck" in your throat.

Try eating a piece/slice of dry bread. It has more ability to help you swallow anything in your throat.

You have already tried liquids. The solid should give you some immediate relief.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a small piece of bread (without the crust) and some peanut butter on it. I try this occasionally and it seems to work. Also, do not eat an enormous amount of peanut butter on the bread. A small amount will suffice.

Make sure you drink some water before and after doing this.

Not magic, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to swallow the water normally, then most likely the tablet isn't actually stuck in your throat any more. The tissue in your throat is very sensitive, and when a tablet gets stuck, it irritates the lining a bit.  When the tablet gets unstuck, the feeling still lingers, making the sensation that the tablet is still stuck.

If you are able to swallow the next bite normally, it's just the lasting sensation you're feeling, not the tablet itself.  The sensation will slowly dissipate on its own without any need to eat bread or anything else.

Answer (score -4):

Tie cotton with good thread. Roll thread on finger and put some drinkable things on that cotton and then swallow it. While pulling back that cotton take care to stuck that cotton with tablet. If not stuck then swallow again or drink saliva or little water. keep doing until relief. You can also **simply gargle** to wet throat.